# Using Node.js and Passport.js, how can I logout and delete all cookie sessions?

Tags: node.js, cookies, passport.js

On startup, I use a cookie session as follows:

```
const cookieSession = require("cookie-session");
const myCookieSession = cookieSession({
  name: "session",
  keys: ["..."],
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
});
app.use(myCookieSession);
```

When logging out with Passport.js, I use the following code:

```
delete req.session;
req.logout();
```

This logs a user out on the current device, but I want to log the user out on all devices.

How do I do this with cookie sessions?